# Why is this code not putting the NSArray objects into the NSMutableArray?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have a .txt file with 7 TAB-delimited strings in it.  I want to take the 7 strings, one at a time, and separate each of them by the tab delimiter into an array, then put that array into a Mutable array, from where I can process each of the 7 processed strings.  Here is my code:

```
NSMutableArray *arrayOfSplitStrings = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];

for(int i = 1; i <= inputStrings.count - 1; i++)  {        
    NSArray *oneSplitString = [[NSArray alloc]init];
    arrayOfSplitStrings = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    oneSplitString = [inputStrings[i] componentsSeparatedByString:@"\t"];
    [arrayOfSplitStrings addObjectsFromArray: oneSplitString];
}
```

The problem is, when completed, *arrayOfSplitStrings* only has one (1) array in it and it is @""!  I have looked on SO and tried everything I can think of, but it's still not working.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is causing the output array to be re-created, each iteration of the loop, hence it just retains the last line of the file:

```
arrayOfSplitStrings = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

Try:

```
NSMutableArray *arrayOfSplitStrings = [NSMutableArray new];
for (NSUInteger i = 1; i < [inputStrings count]; i++) {
    NSArray *oneSplitString = [[inputStrings[i] componentsSeparatedByString:@"\t"] copy];
    [arrayOfSplitStrings addObject:oneSplitString];
}
```

(note the `for` loop condition change too).

Comment: That puts everything (101 objects) into the one (1) array (*arrayOfSplitStrings*); if I have 7 *inputStrings*, I should have 7 *oneSplitStrings* arrays in *arrayOfSplitStrings*.  (sure hope I haven't confused you)...and the loop has to skip the first row where the tab definitions are.

Comment: @spokane-dude OK, fixed.

Comment: that works!  I can live with the 1st string being separated; I'll just skip it... thanks again for your time, I apppreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The `arrayOfSplitStrings` outside the loop is being hidden by the `NSArray` created inside the loop, remove it.

There is no need to create the `NSArray` `arrayOfSplitStrings` because on the next line a new array is returned, only a declaration is needed.

The for loop can be changes to a for-in loop eliminating the index variable `i`.

There are also some other optimizations possible.

```
NSArray *bodyStrings = [inputStrings subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, inputStrings.count-1)];
NSMutableArray *arrayOfSplitStrings = [NSMutableArray new];
for (NSString *aString in bodyStrings) {
    NSArray *oneSplitString = [aString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\t"];
    [arrayOfSplitStrings addObject:oneSplitString];
}
```

The input:

```
NSArray *inputStrings = @[@"qw\ter", @"as\tdf", @"zx\tcv"];
```

produces:

```
arrayOfSplitStrings: (
        (
        as,
        df
    ),
        (
        zx,
        cv
    )
)
```